# Unable to import moment in Angular 8

Tags: typescript, momentjs, angular8

I am facing this weird issue where by my Angular 8 cannot resolve my moment library.

I have already did a 
`rm -rf node_modules`, `npm install`

package.json:

[image]

Class using moment: 
[image]

When I do a `npm start`, this is the error i faced.

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material-moment-adapter/typings/adapter/moment-date-adapter.d.ts:10:24 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'moment'.

10 import { Moment } from 'moment';
                          ~~~~~~~~
src/app/shared/configurator/base-configurator/base-configurator.component.ts:9:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'moment'.

9 import * as moment from 'moment';
                          ~~~~~~~~
src/app/shared/configurator/util.ts:1:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'moment'.

1 import * as moment from 'moment';
                      ~~~~~~~~
```

Any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: check it out how moment is imported in official examples from angular material: https://stackblitz.com/angular/eyqoeagdrly?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-moment-example.ts .... maybe it will work for you

Comment: i had to do "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true in tsconfig.json  "compilerOptions" and then use it `import * as moment from 'moment';` . Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a compatibility issue with moment 2.25.0
Temporary solution is to downgrade to moment 2.24.0

https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3763

Answer (score 0):

You can try install `material-moment-adapter` and import `MomentDateAdapter`

```
npm i @angular/material-moment-adapter

import { MatMomentDateModule, MomentDateAdapter } from "@angular/material-moment-adapter";
```